# Pass prop value from one class to another

Tags: reactjs

How can I pass the value player below into the class Befunde. I have been trying to figure this out for some time now but unfortunately to no avail

```
render() {
        const {classes, player} = this.props;
        console.log(player)
    return (
      <div className={classes.content}>
      <div className={classes.contentShift}>
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>

          <Befunde />

      </MuiThemeProvider>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
    }
```

This is the class befunde I'm trying to return player within a div tag

**class Befunde**

```
render () {
    const { classes } = this.props;

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
    <div>{this.props.player}</div>

      <Grid container spacing={24}>
        <Grid item xs={3}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}><Refrence/></Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>

          <div>
    {this.state.patients.map(patient => (   
            <div key={patient.id}>

              {patient.Vorname}

            </div>
              ))}
              </div>

          </Paper>
        </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </div>
```

Thanks!

The route looks like this

```
<Route  path="/PlayerFilter/:player" component={({match}) => <FilterB
                                                                        player={match.params.player}/> }/>
```

which leads to the first code block now I want to pass that value unto Befunde.

Comment: Please post your `Befunde` class.

Comment: `<Befunde player={player} />`? You seem to use props anyhow, so what is blocking you here?

Comment: @Icepickle I tried that already but didnt work hence my question

Comment: Didn't work is such a generic thing to say, do you mean it was `null`, in that case is player already there? Note that if you load it in `componentDidMount` or in some async way, it's valid to be `undefined` or `null` upon first render, just handle that case properly and you'll be fine. We don't know how your log looks like or where you are loading the player data, so it's kinda hard to provide you with an answer

Comment: Since `<Befunde player={player} />` did not work, check if 1. `this.props` has what you need. 2. Check is Befunde a class or not. If it's a function then use `props.x` instead of `this.props.x`

Comment: Befunde is a class and the value of player in Befunde is undefined. I havent loaded it in any Componentdidmount or async way. Thanks!

Comment: So, your problem is how to load the player? Where does player come from in your first render method? How is it supposed to be available?

Comment: I sent it in using a route component by matching it with the parameters of a query

Comment: Then show that part of the code (so how you handle the route) because that seems to be the problem at hand (also how you handle getting the player itself in the end)

Comment: just added the route

Comment: issue resolved ended up passing the into a new constructor and sending it to Befunde